# Install mysql in windows

Tags: mysql

Every thing is downloading except the server, I tried deleting it and downloading it again but it didn’t work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrV1C.jpg)

Comment: Install `MYSQL Workbench` it's similar to `MYSQL installer`

Answer (score 0):

You should try **XAMPP** if you can't fix it, it's a easier way to use a sql server.
It's very easy to install and run. Download: https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html